# How to add a ref to functional components that are created dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of `Item`s (divs with an input field) as well as a `handleSaveItem` function. Each `Item` has an `itemId` which should become the value that the user types into the input field (after they click the button). My question is how to get that information, which is in `Item.js`, up to its parent in `App.js`.

I can't use `useRef` in `handleSaveItem` because that wouldn't be calling the hook at the top-level. But if I used `useRef` at the top-level of the `Item` component I don't know how I would pass that ref up to `App`.

Codesandbox appears to be down right now but here's some demo code anyways (simplified): https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-add-new-item-zbqlk

Comment: There are ways to forward a ref. But what is the use case here? is it the value that the element contains? wouldn't that be tied to state? depending on the use case you could probably not use refs and just do a simple DOM query.

Comment: In this use case (looking at the codesandbox). you should just Adjust your individual components to track their value via state. Then you can pass the state up in your button press. Dont pass the index, pass the `itemId` as well, its more explicit

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @JohnRuddell how do I pass the Item's state back up to App though? I thought the general rule of thumb is that the data flow is top -> down. Maybe something is not clicking for me?

Comment: In `item.js` adjust the button onclick. `<button onClick={e => props.handleSaveItem(e, props.itemId, value)}>Save</button>` where `value` is the state value for that item. [**Something like this**](https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-add-new-item-zzc42)

Comment: ah that makes total sense, thank you!